# Accessing attributes in xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Given the following xml, how do I access the record attributes in  node, which is the 2nd record.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <dfs:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/ado/queryFields" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/ado/dataFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:xdado="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/adomapping" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2010-03-28T23:16:33" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-au" xdado:dataModified="" xmlns="">
- <dfs:queryFields>
  <q:Table1 ID="" Builders_Name="" Builders_Email_Address="" Date_Instructed="" Instructed_By="" Policy_Number="" Claim_Number="" Sum_Insured_Building="" Customer_Name="" Street_Address="" Town="" Postcode="" Customer_Phone="" Agent_Phone="" Tennant_Phone="" Event="" Excess="" Date_of_Event="" Number_of_Levels="" Wall_Construction="" Roof_Construction="" Asbestos="" Make_Safe_Required="" Dividing_Fence="" Location_of_Damage="" Urgent="" Comments="" Roof="" Leak_Detect="" Inception_date_of_policy="" Renewal_date_of_policy="" Estimated_cost_of_claim="" Case_manager="" Sum_Insured_Contents="" Sum_Insured_Contents1="" Internal_Assessor_required="" Internal_assessor="" Contact_if_not_insured="" Postal_address_if_differenet_to_risk="" /> 
  </dfs:queryFields>

<dfs:dataFields>
  <d:Table1 ID="" Builders_Name="ss" Builders_Email_Address="sdf" Date_Instructed="2011-08-08" Instructed_By="sdv" Policy_Number="ddd" Claim_Number="ddd" Sum_Insured_Building="34" Customer_Name="asdf" Street_Address="asdf" Town=sdf" Postcode="34" Customer_Phone="a" Agent_Phone="" Tennant_Phone="" Event="Storm" Excess="100.00" Date_of_Event="sdf" Number_of_Levels="1" Wall_Construction="sdf" Roof_Construction="Cement Tile" Asbestos="sdf" Make_Safe_Required="sdf" Dividing_Fence="No" Location_of_Damage="asdf" Urgent="No" Comments="asdf" Roof="Yes" Leak_Detect="No" Inception_date_of_policy="2asdf" Renewal_date_of_policy="2asdf" Estimated_cost_of_claim="" Case_manager="asdf" Sum_Insured_Contents="" Sum_Insured_Contents1="" Internal_Assessor_required="No" Internal_assessor="" Contact_if_not_insured="" Postal_address_if_differenet_to_risk="" /> 
  </dfs:dataFields>
```

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Best to use jquery ajax for this, in my opinion...

In Jquery Ajax it'd be something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../xml/yourxmlfile.xml", 
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) 
    {
        $(xml).find('nodename').each(function()
        {
            var attrvalue = $(this).attr('attributename');
            ...
            do what you want here
        }
    }
});
});
```

If you want to stick to plain javascript, you'd probably need to use regex.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have jQuery and/or don't retrieve this with a controlled AJAX call then you can use:

```
var el = document.createElement("xml");
el.innerHTML = docData;  //xml content
var record = el.getElementsByTagName("d:Table1")[0];
var recor_builders_name = record.attributes["builders_name"].value;
document.write(recor_builders_name); //Do what you need with your record
```

Now, if you use an ajax call, but without jQuery, you can use the responseXML attribute from the call. That element is already a document object, so you can skip the first two lines and set `el = yourAjax.responseXML` instead (or use directly that attribute if you preferr)

*Btw, I assume that xml is a fragment of a much bigger document and that the missing root node close-tag is just a copy-paste error.*